# How to download a file from the jenkins job build folder

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins server running, and for a job I need to download a file which is in the `jobs/builds/buildname` folder.

How to download that file from jenkins job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would use the workspace as suggested by previous post, you can access it within a Pipeline:

```
sh "wget http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/ws/index.txt"
```

Or inside a script:

```
wget http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/ws/index.txt
```

Where `index.txt` is the file you want to download.

Comment: In linux it is and in powershell on windows it is also available.

Comment: is not a PIPELINE native command and in RedHat distributions its not too ;)

Comment: @S.Spieker - Can i do the same programatically using java? I want to download or read  the file which is in Jenkins job folder using java.Thanks.

Comment: what is "ws"? how to identify concrete downstream job?

Comment: `ws` is the workspace

Answer (score 3):

I rock a Unix based development machine and a Unix based Jenkins machine up in the cloud.  This means I can use the [SCP Command](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/) to download the remote file over an ssh connection.  This is the anatomy of my scp commands:

```
scp -i <path/to/ssh.pem/file> <user>@<jenkins.remote.url>:<path/to/remote/file> <local/path/where/download/goes>
```

This works for directories too, for instance I use this to download backups generated by the [ThinBackup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

Answer (score 2):

You had already been given the answer for getting the file from the workspace

`http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/ws/filename.ext`
Obviously replace stuff in `<..>` with values relevant to your setup, and make sure anonymous user has access to read from workspace, else you may have to login.

The only other files you could access are those that are archived from previous job runs.
`http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/<buildnumber>/artifact/filename.ext`
Where `<buildnumber>` is the build number you see in job build history, or one of the permalinks provided by Eldad (such as `lastStableBuild`). But this will only have access to archived artifacts.

You cannot arbitrarily access files from Jenkin's filesystem through the web interface... it wouldn't be very secure if it did let you.

Comment: how to set artifact ? for example my file is at:
http://myjenkins:8080/job/FUTURE/job/GetFullPath/4/execution/node/3/ws/File.txt
http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/<buildnumber>/artifact/File.txt

in this case artifact = /execution/node/3/ws/

how can I get this path ?

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins job's *build* folder is meant for logging and plugins reports. You should not need to access it directly.

If you must, you can access it relative to the workspace: **$WORKSPACE/../builds/$BUILD_ID/**

You can also replace the **$BUILD_ID** with one of the links Jenkins creates:
lastFailedBuild
lastStableBuild
lastSuccessfulBuild
lastUnstableBuild
lastUnsuccessfulBuild

I hope this helps.

Comment: I dont have access to the machine directly. is there a way I can download the file without using scp from the machine ??

Comment: You can use the access to workspace via URL (http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/ws/), but you'll have to copy the file over to the workspace out of the relevant build before the build is over.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out this path should work, I like to highlight that the "ws" is a directory in Jenkins:

```
http://<servername:port>/job/<your job>/ws/<your file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Package lynx (Command line browser)

```
    $ apt-get install lynx
```

or

```
    $ yum install lynx
```

then use the command

```
   # lynx http://<servername:port>/job/<jobname>/ws/file
```

The App Will Ask you to allow cookies and if there are authentication  will direct you to login page like the browser.