# How do you display a clickable repo link in the Jenkins output?

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins Console logs it says:

`Obtained jenkins/some.jenkinsfile from git ssh://mygitserver.myorg.com/my/git/repo.git`

so I have to copy / paste / edit to get that repo then click about to the Jenkinsfile in your browser.

When you're doing this multiple times every day it becomes a major headache.

Is there anyway to get a simple clickable link?

Comment: Just add this link to the Job Description using a HTML link, you can do it the project configuration page or via pipeline code, then it will be available both on the the build page and on the execution panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest crafting an output that would then become clickable. i.e. declare the link then specify the file using a variable.

```
script { println("https://yourRepoUrl.com/jenkins/${downloadFile}) }
```

Alternatively, you could download the file from within the pipeline. [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671522/10852935)